# USB Tuner driver not detected

Tags: usb, kernel-modules, dvb

I am using a DVB Tuner, USB tuner. I have added driver to the kernel and it is being registered. But when the device is connected, it doesnt invoke the probe function.

Is there anything I have to add? Like should the device driver be mapped to the device or something? and please explain how a driver is loaded, based on the type of usb device. The kernel I am using is linux 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know for certain that your device works with the driver?  If so:

**Firmware**

Some devices also need additional firmware.  Unfortunately, the method needed to extract the firwmware and install it, depends on the device.  Some require you to download a copy of the Windows driver and use tools to extract the firmware.  Google will help you here.

**Changed Vendor & Product IDs**

Sometimes vendors change the vendor and product ID, which is the method drivers use to recognise compatible devices.

These IDs are hard-coded in the driver.  Fortunately, modern device drivers have a method to temporarily add vendor and product Ids at runtime.

Use `lsusb` to get the IDs of your device:

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1234:abcd Acme Corp DVB Tuner
```

Unplug your device and unload the driver (to get a fresh starting point):

```
# rmmod acme_dvb
```

Next, load your driver:

```
# modprobe acme_dvb
```

Finally, tell the driver about the new USB IDs:

```
# echo 1234 abcd > sys/bus/usb/drivers/acme_dvb/new_id
```

Note that the exact path may vary.

Plug your device in and check if it's been recognised:

```
# dmesg
```

If this works, the right thing to do would report it as a bug against the driver so that hopefully the maitainer will add the new IDs.

Comment: Hi garethTheRed,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly I am not able to use lsusb, since I'm using it on a set-top box. It doesn't have any of those binaries. But yes, thanks for that command to tell about new USB IDs. Now I finally get the device node, but getting two frontends, where only one is supposed to be created.

Comment: What do you mean by *two frontends*?  Also, add the make/model (and maybe USB Id) of the device to your question.

Comment: I mean usually there'll be just one device node created in /dev.. like /dev/device/adapter0/frontend0.. But now its like, there are /dev/device/adapter0 and /dev/device/adapter1/frontend0

Comment: My tuner is Happauge Ministick 2 with USB id 2040:f900

Comment: Having two nodes in `/dev` is not necessarily a problem.  Have you read the [Gentoo article](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hauppauge_WinTV_Ministick) on installing this device? You can't use it as a step-by-step guide, but it should give you some clues. For instance, it seems you need to install firmware.